# Show By Means Of An Example limit exists

Tags: calculus, limits

Show by means of an example that lim as x approaches a [f(x)+g(x)] may exist even though neither the lim as x? I know if whatever f(x) is, g(x) will be -f(x). How would I write this more concisely?

Comment: The eccentric use of capitals makes this surprisingly hard to read.  But $g(x)=-f(x)+h(x)$ where $h(x)$ has a nice limit will always work.

Comment: Sorry, just fixed it. Could you elaborate more on that, I'm not totally clear when you say h(x) has a nice limit will always work.

Comment: Take any function $h(x)$ such that $\lim_{x\to a}h(x)$ exists.  Then let $g(x)=-f(x)+h(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

You need a function $f$ that has no limit at a point $a$ and another function $h$ that has a limit at $a$, (say the limit is $z\in\mathbb R$) and define $g$ as $g=h-f$. Then you can show that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow a}[f(x)+g(x)]=\lim_{x\rightarrow a}[f(x)+h(x)-f(x)]=\lim_{x\rightarrow a}[h(x)]=z.$$
On the other hand, $$\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x), \lim_{x\rightarrow a}[h(x)-f(x)]$$ both don't exist as $f$ was chosen such that it has no limit at $a$.

An example would be $a=0$, $f(x)=1/x$ and $g(x)=x$.

Answer (score 0):

Take
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}1\text{ if }x\in\Bbb Q\\0\text{ if }x\notin\Bbb Q\end{cases}$$
and
$$g(x)=\begin{cases}0\text{ if }x\in\Bbb Q\\1\text{ if }x\notin\Bbb Q\end{cases}$$

Comment: So is this saying whatever f(x) is g(x) will be the inverse of that basically. So either way if you add these up it will equal 1?